# Flutter: The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.5.20 and higher

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, gradle

Good evening. I have been struggling for days with the following error in Flutter:

The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.5.20 and higher.
The following dependencies do not satisfy the required version:
project ':flutter_launch' -> org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.50

There were similar issues already answered but nothing is helping. My colleague doesn't have this issue. We compared the following files and they are the same: pubspec.yaml.....app\build.gradle...android\build.gradle files

I even did a Flutter upgrade and a fresh Android studio install on a different laptop

This is my android\build.gradle file:

```
  buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.0'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        //classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.13'
        //implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:latest.release'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```